# Set static page public directory through Parse-Server command line

Tags: parse-server

I'm able to run a parse server like this:

```
parse-server --appId APPLICATION_ID --masterKey MASTER_KEY --databaseURI mongodb://localhost/test
```

But I'm wondering if it's possible to set the public path for static page when using parse-server command line ?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
parse-server --appId APPLICATION_ID --masterKey MASTER_KEY --databaseURI mongodb://localhost/test --publicServerURL https://myaddress.com
```

For the full list of available options, run `parse-server --help` or take a look at: http://parseplatform.org/parse-server/api/master/ParseServerOptions.html